# Regex searching for string that contains 3 or more digits

Tags: c#, regex, numbers

I'm trying to find a way to extract a word from a string only if it contains 3 or more digits/numbers in that word. It would also need to return the entire text like

> `TX-23443` or `FUX3329442` etc...

From what I found

```
\w*\d\w*
```

won't return the any letters before the dash like the first example?

All the example I found online don't seem to be working for me. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can u show how your string looks. What is the exact output with what have you tried so far??

Comment: I forgot to mention it would also need to return the entire text like

Comment: I forgot to mention it would also need to return the entire text like TX-23443 or FUX3329442 etc...  From what I found "\w*\d\w*" won't return the any letters before the dash like the first example?

Comment: try this: \w*\d{3,}\w*, or if you need dashes also: [-]*\w*[-]*\d{3,}[-]*\w*[-]*

Comment: use [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41372081/edit) button link to update your question. with your string and expected string

Comment: @mike11d11 please check if my edit is ok. You're looking for string contains **3** or more digits, right? Included information from your comment in question.

Answer (score 3):

IF I understand your question correctly you wanted to find all the string which contains 3+ consequtive numbers in it such as **TX-23443 or FUX3329442** so you wanted to extract `TX-23443` and `FUX3329442` even if it contains `-` in between the string. So here is the solution which might help you

```
string InpStr = "TX-23443 or FUX3329442";
MatchCollection ms = Regex.Matches(InpStr, @"[A-Za-z-]*\d{3,}");
foreach(Match m in ms)
{
    Console.WriteLine(m);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This one should do the trick assuming your "words" have only the standard latin word characters: A-Z, a-z, 0-9 and _.

```cs
Regex word_with_3_digits = new Regex(@"(?#!cs word_with_3_digits Rev:20161129_0600)
    # Match word having at least three digits.
    \b            # Anchor to word boundary.
    (?:           # Loop to find three digits.
      [A-Za-z_]*  # Zero or more non-digit word chars.
      \d          # Match one digit at a time.
    ){3}          # End loop to find three digits.
    \w*           # Match remainder of word.
    \b            # Anchor to word boundary.
    ", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

Answer (score 1):

In javascript I would write a regex like this:

> \S*\d{3,}\S*

I've prepared an [online test](https://regex101.com/r/KxxSjX/2).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string strToCount = "Asd343DSFg534434";
int count = Regex.Matches(strToCount,"[0-9]").Count;
```

Answer (score 0):

This one seems to be working for me even if there is a dash at the end as well.

[-]*\w*[-]*\d{3,}[-]*\w*[-]*\w*